# Assign event handler to element defined in resource dictionary created via data binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, resourcedictionary

I have a C# XAML Windows 8 project.

HubPage.xaml contains a `GridView` named *HubGridView*. *HubGridView* uses a custom `ItemTemplateSelector` named *HubItemTemplateSelector*. The *HubItemTemplateSelector* selects a `DataTemplate` named *AdDataTemplate* defined in a `ResourceDictionary` file named *HubResourceDictionary.xaml*. The *AdDataTemplate* contains an `AdControl` element named *HubAdControl*.

I need to be able to set the `HubAdControl`s `ErrorOccurred` event handler to a method defined in code-behind somewhere.  How do I accomplish this?

**HubPage.xaml:**

```
<GridView x:Name="HubGridView" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource HubItemTemplateSelector}" />
```

**HubResourceDictionary.xaml:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AdDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <UI:AdControl x:Name="HubAdControl" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works just like you think it would:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <TextBlock Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded_1">Hello World</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>

<GridView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
```

in my sample there, Loaded is raised every single time the TextBox is rendered - which is for every single item bound to the ItemsSource of the GridView. You could just as easily use another event like OnError or whatever. It does not matter that it is in resources. It does not matter that it is the result of binding to a repeater.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured this out by now, but I had the same problem.

I'm not sure if I understood Jerry's answer 100%. I tried putting the AdControl in a resource file like this:

**Templates.xaml**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AdTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Margin="70,40,70,140" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ui:AdControl 
                ApplicationId="d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab" 
                AdUnitId="10043030" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Height="600" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="300" ErrorOccurred="OnAdError" />
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then in my xaml I referred to the DataTemplate using a DataTemplateSelector. I tried creating the OnAdError event handler in the xaml code behind where I used the DataTemplate. I got a runtime exception, the resource template needed the OnAdError method.

Maybe there is something I missed, I'm certainly not an expert in XAML nor Windows 8(.1) apps. However, what I ended up doing was creating a UserContol with the  control together with the OnAdError handler in the code behind, and referred to this UserControl in the resource file. Now everything is working as expected and I got a bonus out of it that I can gather all ad logic in this user control. Next step is to change AdUnitId dynamically :)